# refreshing data in jscroll pane swings

Tags: java, swing

I have a main panel in which there is another panel to which i am applying scrolling.This panel in turn contains 2 panels.

Now when i apply scrolling the scroll bar appears.

The problem is when I dynamically add data from the user screen partially.....the data appears onto the screen but I am not able to scroll it panel down and the data below the scroll bar is not seen properly.

```
generalInformationPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
generalInformationPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1050, 500);
generalInformationPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

gd_GeneralInformationUpperPanel = new JPanel();
gd_GeneralInformationUpperPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 1050, 700);
gd_GeneralInformationUpperPanel.setLayout(null);
gd_GeneralInformationUpperPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
js1 = new JScrollPane(gd_GeneralInformationUpperPanel,
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
js1.setBounds(0, 0, 950, 450);
js1.setVisible(true);
generalInformationPanel.add(js1);

add(generalInformationPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what the problem is, because the code does not show enough of what could fail (besides using absolute layout, which, besides being a common cause of trouble, may well be the cause of your problems too). For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: +1, @kiheru, that is the exact problem. Scrollbars appear when the preferred size of the component added to the scrollpane is greater than the size of the scrollpane. Since a null layout is being used the preferred size is 0, so scrollbars will never appear.